# If racism is viewing negatively, what is it called when viewing positively?

Tags: single-word-requests

If racism is viewing and treating people **negatively** because on their race, what is it called when viewing and treating people **positively** because of their race?

Comment: affirmative action

Comment: If you think one person is better because of their race, that means you think other people are worse than them because of their race. So it's still racism.

Comment: Another element is *patronizing*, when you say "Oh, your people make the best...lawyers, musicians, waiters, dancers." You believe it and no one else does.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, white supremacists are racist because they consider white people to be inherently superior to all other racial groups, not because they consider black people to be inferior. Their feeling that black people are inferior is a result if their conviction of their own superiority to all other races.

Answer (score 3):

Racism is the belief that people are inherently more or less valuable due to their race. It does not matter whether the person with the belief thinks this is positive or negative; either way, they are judging people’s value by their race rather than as individuals.

The same logic applies to sexism, nationalism, etc.

Comment: Yes, and it can be harmful as well.